# Unity support for an app Split

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, google-play-services

I just built an app for Android using Unity3D. The app weighs **200mb**. During testing I used to build a single apk which always worked. Now that I uploaded it on PlayStore, I had to use Unity's built in split feature which creates an *apk* and an *obb* file.

My problem is that now the app isn't working. It seems like the obb file isn't being loaded properly and the app doesn't find the files.

I have some assets in StreamingAssets folder which are loaded dynamically and the app doesn't seem to be able to find these along with the other scenes.

What I did to try to fix this with no success:

- Added **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permissions
- Added **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permissions
- Added a plugin to force permissions dialog [Unity Android Permissions](https://github.com/Over17/UnityAndroidPermissions)
- Set to `false` **unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog** in the android manifest
- Added GooglePlayObbDownloader in my project but it seems to crash the app because of the missing License. (I can't retrieve the license)

What am I doing wrong? 
I had a working app, then I enabled **Split Application Binary** in `Player Settings > Publishing Settings` and it stopped working. Disabling the feature, the app works but can't upload it on Google Play as it has a 100MB file limit.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Unity documentation doesn't say anything other than in some cases you may have to download the obb manually. I'm pretty sure it's being downloaded in my case because I tested to see if it exists and it does.

Comment: how are you retrieving the StreamingAssets and the streamingAssetsPath ? Please share that code. And what's the error that you are getting ?

Comment: In the first scene I'm using UniWebView loading a local html file. Loading it like below


`string url = UniWebViewHelper.StreamingAssetURLForPath("Home/public/index.html");`
`uwv.Load(url);`

Comment: @AniSinanaj Did you ever find a resolution? We've got the same issue.

Comment: @Kieron I put the web assets under `/plugins/android/assets/` this way they get copied to the main package while all the rest is split and put to the OBB package. Let me know if this isn't clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned using UniWebView. The documentation recommends placing your web files in the `Assets/Plugins/Android/assets/` folder.

> If you are using "Split Application Binary" for Android build (obb files), you should not put your local HTML files under StreamingAssets folder. Instead, you need to put them to Assets/Plugins/Android/assets/ and then you can use the same way as you did for normal streaming assets resource to load it from the new location.

https://docs.uniwebview.com/guide/loading-local-files.html#using-split-application-binary.

Unfortunately this will simply move the files from the .obb to the .apk file, which might push you over the 100mb limit again.